# In python, how to parse a multi-layered JSON?

Tags: python, json

Please, in Python 3 I have a script to access an API using requests, which I then turn into JSON

However, some information is at deep sublevels and I can't seem to access it. See below:

```
import requests

headers = {"Accept" : "application/json"}

url = "http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/20050"

try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc) 
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)

projects = r.json()

try:
    NomeAutor= str(projects['DetalheMateria']['Materia']['Autoria']['Autor']['NomeAutor'])
    print("ok")
except KeyError:
    NomeAutor = None                
    print("keyerror")
except TypeError:
    NomeAutor = None                     
    print("typerror")

print(NomeAutor)
```

When I try to capture the "NomeAutor" the error is typerror

Here is the content of projects:

```
{'DetalheMateria': {'@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', '@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/dados/DetalheMateriav5.xsd', 'Metadados': {'Versao': '03/12/2019 21:36:18', 'VersaoServico': '5', 'DataVersaoServico': 
'2017-02-01', 'DescricaoDataSet': 'Dados básicos da matéria, incluindo autoria, norma gerada e outras informações. A partir de fevereiro de 2019, os requerimentos de comissões permanentes passam a ser numerados com a mesma sistemática dos requerimentos das comissões temporárias, seguindo, portanto, o padrão: REQ 99/2019 - SIGLA_COMISSÃO. Dessa forma, para se buscar um requerimento de determinada comissão (com ano a partir de 2019), deve-se informar .../materia/sigla/número/ano?comissao=sigla da comissão.'}, 'Materia': {'IdentificacaoMateria': {'CodigoMateria': '20050', 'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'SF', 'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Senado Federal', 'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'PLC', 'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'PROJETO DE LEI DA CÂMARA', 'NumeroMateria': '00035', 'AnoMateria': '1988', 'DescricaoObjetivoProcesso': 'Revisora', 'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria': 'PLC 35/1988', 'IndicadorTramitando': 
'Não'}, 'DadosBasicosMateria': {'EmentaMateria': "DECLARA FERIADO NACIONAL O DIA 20 DE NOVEMBRO, ANIVERSARIO DA MORTE   \n      DE ZUMBI DOS PALMARES, CONSAGRADO PELA COMUNIDADE AFRO-BRASILEIRA     \n      COMO 'DIA NACIONAL DA CONSCIENCIA NEGRA.'                          
   \n      ", 'IndicadorComplementar': 'Não', 'DataApresentacao': '1987-12-01', 'DataLeitura': '1987-12-01'}, 'Autoria': {'Autor': [{'NomeAutor': 'Câmara dos Deputados', 'SiglaTipoAutor': 'CAMARA', 'DescricaoTipoAutor': 'Câmara dos Deputados', 'NumOrdemAutor': '1', 'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}]}, 'Iniciativa': {'SiglaTipoIniciativa': 'DEPUTADO', 'DescricaoTipoIniciativa': 'Deputado', 'DescricaoIniciativa': 'BENEDITA DA SILVA'}, 'OrigemMateria': {'SiglaCasaOrigem': 'CD', 'NomeCasaOrigem': 'Câmara dos Deputados'}, 'CasaIniciadoraNoLegislativo': {'SiglaCasaIniciadora': 'SF', 'NomeCasaIniciadora': 'Senado Federal'}, 'OutrosNumerosDaMateria': {'OutroNumeroDaMateria': {'IdentificacaoMateria': {'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'CD', 'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Câmara dos Deputados', 'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 
'PL', 'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'PROJETO DE LEI', 'NumeroMateria': '00293', 'AnoMateria': 
'1987'}, 'DescricaoTipoNumeracao': 'CasaIniciadora'}}, 'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': [{'NumeroAutuacao': '1', 'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '1996-01-23', 'CodigoSituacao': '28', 'SiglaSituacao': 'ARQVD', 'DescricaoSituacao': 'ARQUIVADA AO FINAL DA LEGISLATURA'}, 'Local': {'DataLocal': '1996-01-23', 'CodigoLocal': '206', 'TipoLocal': 'A', 'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF', 'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal', 'SiglaLocal': 'SSEXP', 'NomeLocal': 'SUBSECRETARIA DE EXPEDIENTE'}}]}}, 'OutrasInformacoes': {'Servico': [{'NomeServico': 'EmendaMateria', 'DescricaoServico': 'Emendas da matéria', 'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/emendas/20050?v=6'}, {'NomeServico': 'MovimentacaoMateria', 'DescricaoServico': 'Movimentações da matéria, como tramitações, despachos e prazos.\n      Evoluções:\n      14/8/2019\n      - criada nova Tag "DeliberacoesMPV" para as deliberações de MPV;\n 
     - criada nova Tag "DescricaoItemCalendario" subord', 'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/movimentacoes/20050?v=6'}, {'NomeServico': 'RelatoriaMateria', 'DescricaoServico': 'Relatoria atual e relatorias encerradas (histórico) da matéria', 'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/relatorias/20050?v=5'}, {'NomeServico': 'TextoMateria', 'DescricaoServico': 'Textos da matéria. \n      Evoluções da versão: \n      28/8/2019 - incluída a tag "AutoriaTexto", sob a tag "Texto".', 'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/textos/20050?v=5'}, {'NomeServico': 'VotacaoMateria', 'DescricaoServico': 'Votações da matéria', 'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/votacoes/20050?v=5'}, {'NomeServico': 'VotacoesComissao', 'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/votacaoComissao/materia/PLC/00035/1988?v=1'}]}, 'UrlGlossario': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/glossario/lista'}}}
```

Please does anyone know why the information is not captured?

And is there any simpler way to capture information on a deep JSON sublevel without having to type it all the way?

Comment: Paste it into something like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu and explore the tree one by one. `Author` is an *array*, so you need to add an `[0]`, or more likely you're supposed to loop through that array, as there may be more than one author.

Comment: Try doing it step by step, e.g. detalhe = projects['DetalheMateria'], then materia = detalhe['Materia'] et cetera on different lines. You'll find the line that gives the error.

Comment: Thank you very much @deceze I did not know this website. It worked now

Comment: Just for the record: once unserialized (by the `response.json()` call), what you have in `projects` is a plain Python dict. IOW, this has absolutely nothing to do with json, python-requests, APIs etc, it's just plain basic Python dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- The data you are loading is not a valid `json`.
- `Autor` is a `list` of dicts, but you are trying to access it as a `dict`.

---

I suggest you to try `python-benedict`, it's an open-source `dict` subclass with many features, including standardized I/O operations and keypath support. (Disclosure: I am the author). https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict

Installation: `pip install python-benedict`

Then:

```py
from benedict import benedict as bdict

data_source = {
    'DetalheMateria': {
        '@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
        '@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/dados/DetalheMateriav5.xsd',
        'Metadados': {
            'Versao': '03/12/2019 21:36:18',
            'VersaoServico': '5',
            'DataVersaoServico': '2017-02-01',
            'DescricaoDataSet': 'Dados básicos da matéria, incluindo autoria, norma gerada e outras informações. A partir de fevereiro de 2019, os requerimentos de comissões permanentes passam a ser numerados com a mesma sistemática dos requerimentos das comissões temporárias, seguindo, portanto, o padrão: REQ 99/2019 - SIGLA_COMISSÃO. Dessa forma, para se buscar um requerimento de determinada comissão (com ano a partir de 2019), deve-se informar .../materia/sigla/número/ano?comissao=sigla da comissão.'
        },
        'Materia': {
            'IdentificacaoMateria': {
                'CodigoMateria': '20050',
                'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'SF',
                'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Senado Federal',
                'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'PLC',
                'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'PROJETO DE LEI DA CÂMARA',
                'NumeroMateria': '00035',
                'AnoMateria': '1988',
                'DescricaoObjetivoProcesso': 'Revisora',
                'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria': 'PLC 35/1988',
                'IndicadorTramitando': 'Não'
            },
            'DadosBasicosMateria': {
                'EmentaMateria': "DECLARA FERIADO NACIONAL O DIA 20 DE NOVEMBRO, ANIVERSARIO DA MORTE   \n      DE ZUMBI DOS PALMARES, CONSAGRADO PELA COMUNIDADE AFRO-BRASILEIRA     \n      COMO 'DIA NACIONAL DA CONSCIENCIA NEGRA.'                          \n      ",
                'IndicadorComplementar': 'Não',
                'DataApresentacao': '1987-12-01',
                'DataLeitura': '1987-12-01'
            },
            'Autoria': {
                'Autor': [
                    {'NomeAutor': 'Câmara dos Deputados', 'SiglaTipoAutor': 'CAMARA', 'DescricaoTipoAutor': 'Câmara dos Deputados', 'NumOrdemAutor': '1', 'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}
                ]
            },
            'Iniciativa': {
                'SiglaTipoIniciativa': 'DEPUTADO',
                'DescricaoTipoIniciativa': 'Deputado',
                'DescricaoIniciativa': 'BENEDITA DA SILVA'
            },
            'OrigemMateria': {
                'SiglaCasaOrigem': 'CD',
                'NomeCasaOrigem': 'Câmara dos Deputados'
            },
            'CasaIniciadoraNoLegislativo': {
                'SiglaCasaIniciadora': 'SF',
                'NomeCasaIniciadora': 'Senado Federal'
            },
            'OutrosNumerosDaMateria': {
                'OutroNumeroDaMateria': {
                    'IdentificacaoMateria': {
                        'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'CD',
                        'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Câmara dos Deputados',
                        'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'PL',
                        'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'PROJETO DE LEI',
                        'NumeroMateria': '00293',
                        'AnoMateria': '1987'
                    },
                    'DescricaoTipoNumeracao': 'CasaIniciadora'
                }
            },
            'SituacaoAtual': {
                'Autuacoes': {
                    'Autuacao': [
                        {
                            'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
                            'Situacao': {
                                'DataSituacao': '1996-01-23',
                                'CodigoSituacao': '28',
                                'SiglaSituacao': 'ARQVD',
                                'DescricaoSituacao': 'ARQUIVADA AO FINAL DA LEGISLATURA'
                            },
                            'Local': {
                                'DataLocal': '1996-01-23',
                                'CodigoLocal': '206',
                                'TipoLocal': 'A',
                                'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
                                'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
                                'SiglaLocal': 'SSEXP',
                                'NomeLocal': 'SUBSECRETARIA DE EXPEDIENTE'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            'OutrasInformacoes': {
                'Servico': [
                    {
                        'NomeServico': 'EmendaMateria',
                        'DescricaoServico': 'Emendas da matéria',
                        'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/emendas/20050?v=6'
                    },
                    {
                        'NomeServico': 'MovimentacaoMateria',
                        'DescricaoServico': 'Movimentações da matéria, como tramitações, despachos e prazos.\n      Evoluções:\n      14/8/2019\n      - criada nova Tag "DeliberacoesMPV" para as deliberações de MPV;\n - criada nova Tag "DescricaoItemCalendario" subord',
                        'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/movimentacoes/20050?v=6'
                    },
                    {
                        'NomeServico': 'RelatoriaMateria',
                        'DescricaoServico': 'Relatoria atual e relatorias encerradas (histórico) da matéria',
                        'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/relatorias/20050?v=5'
                    },
                    {
                        'NomeServico': 'TextoMateria',
                        'DescricaoServico': 'Textos da matéria. \n      Evoluções da versão: \n      28/8/2019 - incluída a tag "AutoriaTexto", sob a tag "Texto".',
                        'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/textos/20050?v=5'
                    },
                    {
                        'NomeServico': 'VotacaoMateria',
                        'DescricaoServico': 'Votações da matéria',
                        'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/votacoes/20050?v=5'
                    },
                    {
                        'NomeServico': 'VotacoesComissao',
                        'UrlServico': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/votacaoComissao/materia/PLC/00035/1988?v=1'
                    }
                ]
            },
            'UrlGlossario': 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/glossario/lista'
        }
    }
}

data = bdict(data_source)

# once your url will return a valid json you could just do:
# data = bdict.from_json('http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/20050')

author = data[['DetalheMateria', 'Materia', 'Autoria', 'Autor']][0]
# or: author = data['DetalheMateria.Materia.Autoria.Autor'][0]
author_name = author['NomeAutor']
print(author_name) # --> Câmara dos Deputados
```